# Redis for frequently changed market information

Tags: .net, wcf, redis

The current approach in our software environment is to have several WCF services in an distributed SOA infrastructure. There are more than one service who provide the front website with information from stock exchange like stocks, bonds, currencies, mutual funds for example.

The webservices query the database and we have ThreadCache straight from .net framework which caches the information for 3-5 minutes. If the cache is expired, it would be the enduser that invokes the method that is going to retrieve new information from the database. So the website is pretty fast except for the one that invokes the webservice with expired data....that user will have a pretty slow reponse time... probably about 10-20 second :/

I want to feed this market information to a Redis service running on windows server in every 5 minutes. The WCF services would the get information from REDIS instead of database.

My big question is how would be the best approach to have data feeder that is updating the REDIS service with new information, running on the same machine?

- Windows service running in every 5 minutes
- Daemon running every 5 minutes from an workload scheduler
- ..Or maybe I can implement some method in Redis and he himself (REDIS) would check if
  the data has expired and then invoke some methods that updated the REDIS data storage.

gimme you opinions ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my opinions

> The webservices query the database and we have ThreadCache straight
>   from .net framework which caches the information for 3-5 minutes. If
>   the cache is expired, it would be the enduser that invokes the method
>   that is going to retrieve new information from the database. So the
>   website is pretty fast except for the one that invokes the webservice
>   with expired data....that user will have a pretty slow reponse time...
>   probably about 10-20 second :/

Why do you need a service layer ? If it's only for caching data, I highly recommand you to query directly a distributed cache using AppFabric or simply Redis. Another layer seems to be useless in your case, especially as the code appears to be badly coupled with your web site.

> - Windows service running in every 5 minutes
> - Daemon running every 5
>     minutes from an workload scheduler ..
> - Or maybe I can implement some
>     method in Redis and he himself (REDIS) would check if the data has
>     expired and then invoke some methods that updated the REDIS data
>     storage.

Windows Service or Daemon, it's quite the same and it's the recommanded way to setup background processing. I am familiar with [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/), and I find it really powerfull.
Even if Redis now supports Keyspace Notifications, it's not possible to invoke directly something written in .net.

Your data expire after 5 minutes ? Ok, but run the task every minute in background to preload/precache the data. It will always be fast for the end user as you will never have to reload it.

Finally another great feature of Redis is [PubSub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub). It's easy to notify all subscribers when something has changed in Redis. With only a few lines, It allow you to implement local cache invalidation on all your web sites and avoid not synced nodes.

> I want to feed this market information to a Redis service running on
>   windows server in every 5 minutes. The WCF services would the get
>   information from REDIS instead of database.

Currently the Redis port on Windows is not production quality but can be used for development purposes on Windows (Server) environments. I use it since a few months and find it quite stable but it's recommanded to run Redis on a Linux environnement.